# iOS overwrite EXIF flash property with new value for front camera flash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, alassetslibrary, cgimage

I'm trying to change the `kCGImagePropertyExifFlash` property of the Exif dictionary. My app offers front facing flash modes, so I'm trying to change this Exif value. No matter what I do when I go to save the `newImageData` using `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum` method of `ALAssetsLibrary`, it removes the value I set.

I'd appreciate any help offered.

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:
[self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] 
completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
{
    if (imageSampleBuffer && !error)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef metadataDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, imageSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

        NSDictionary *metadata = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)metadataDict];

        CFRelease(metadataDict);

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

        if (metadata && imageData)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *newMetaData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];

            NSMutableDictionary *exifMetadata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
            [metadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]];

            if (self.isUsingFrontCamera && exifMetadata)
            {
                if (self.flashButton.flashMode == On)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@"On, Fired" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                }
                else if (self.flashButton.flashMode == Off)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@"Off, did not fire" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                }
                else if (self.frontFlashAutoDidFire)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@"Auto, Fired" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                }
             }

             [newMetaData setObject:exifMetadata forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

             NSData *newImageData = [self writeMetadataIntoImageData:imageData metadata:newMetaData];

             [ALAssetsLibrary.new writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:newImageData metadata:nil completionBlock:nil];
         }
     }
}

- (NSData *)writeMetadataIntoImageData:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata
{
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) imageData, NULL);

    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source);

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];

    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)data, UTI, 1, NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) metadata);

    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

    CFRelease(destination);
    CFRelease(source);

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out; it turns out the `kCGImagePropertyExifFlash` is an `NSCFNumber`, not an `NSCFString`, which was my problem. I was able to log the default integer values for the flash modes:

- On, Fired is a value of 9
- Off, did not fire is a value of 16
- Auto, did not fire is a value of 24
- Auto, Fired is a value of 25
- If the hardware device doesn't have flash support, the value is 32
- Unsure of any other possible values, perhaps related to when the flash isn't available if it's too warm.

Code:

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:
[self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] 
completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
{
    if (imageSampleBuffer && !error)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef metadataDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(NULL, imageSampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);

        NSDictionary *metadata = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary *)metadataDict];

        CFRelease(metadataDict);

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

        if (metadata && imageData)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *newMetaData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];

            NSMutableDictionary *exifMetadata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
            [metadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]];

            if (self.isUsingFrontCamera && exifMetadata)
            {
                if (self.flashButton.flashMode == On)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@(9) forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                }
                else if (self.flashButton.flashMode == Off)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@(16) forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                }
                else if (self.flashButton.flashMode == Auto)
                {
                    [exifMetadata setObject:@(24) forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];

                    if (self.frontFlashAutoDidFire)
                    {
                        [exifMetadata setObject:@(25) forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifFlash];
                    }
                }
            }

            [newMetaData setObject:exifMetadata forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

            [ALAssetsLibrary.new writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:newMetaData completionBlock:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As i ran into the same sort of question while developing an iOS app using the camera, I looked up some typical EXIF keys, and their standard translations.

Here is the EXIF flash property description :

### IFD       Exif

```
Code        37385 (hex 0x9209)
```

```
Name        Flash
```

### Description

```
Indicates the status of flash when the image was shot.

Bit 0 indicates the flash firing status, bits 1 and 2 indicate the flash return status, bits 3 and 4 indicate the flash mode, bit 5 indicates whether the flash function is present, and bit 6 indicates "red eye" mode.

Values for bit 0 indicating whether the flash fired.
0 = Flash did not fire
1 = Flash fired

Values for bits 1 and 2 indicating the status of returned light.
00 = No strobe return detection function
01 = reserved
10 = Strobe return light not detected
11 = Strobe return light detected

Values for bits 3 and 4 indicating the camera's flash mode.
00 = unknown
01 = Compulsory flash firing
10 = Compulsory flash suppression
11 = Auto mode

Values for bit 5 indicating the presence of a flash function.
0 = Flash function present
1 = No flash function

Values for bit 6 indicating the camera's red-eye mode.
0 = No red-eye reduction mode or unknown
1 = Red-eye reduction supported

Not all combinations make sense though. The specification defines these combined values:

hex 0000 = Flash did not fire
hex 0001 = Flash fired
hex 0005 = Strobe return light not detected
hex 0007 = Strobe return light detected
hex 0009 = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode
hex 000D = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light not detected
hex 000F = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light detected
hex 0010 = Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode
hex 0018 = Flash did not fire, auto mode
hex 0019 = Flash fired, auto mode
hex 001D = Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected
hex 001F = Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected
hex 0020 = No flash function
hex 0041 = Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode
hex 0045 = Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected
hex 0047 = Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected
hex 0049 = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode
hex 004D = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected
hex 004F = Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected
hex 0059 = Flash fired, auto mode, red-eye reduction mode
hex 005D = Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected, red-eye reduction mode
hex 005F = Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected, red-eye reduction mode
```

Using hex to decimal conversion and objective-C, here is a method to translate the enum given by a call to :

```
[[exifDictionary objectForKey : @"Flash"] integerValue]
```

into a NSString description

```
-(NSString *) translateFlashEnumToNSString: (long) flash
{
    switch (flash) {
        case 0:
            return @"Flash did not fire";
        case 1:
            return @"Flash did fire";
        case 5:
            return @"Strobe return light not detected";
        case 7:
            return @"Strobe return light detected";
        case 9:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode";
        case 13:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light not detected";
        case 15:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, return light detected";
        case 16:
            return @"Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode";
        case 24:
            return @"Flash did not fire, auto mode";
        case 25:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode";
        case 29:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected";
        case 31:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected";
        case 32:
            return @"No flash function";
        case 65:
            return @"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode";
        case 69:
            return @"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected";
        case 71:
            return @"Flash fired, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected";
        case 73:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode";
        case 77:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light not detected";
        case 79:
            return @"Flash fired, compulsory flash mode, red-eye reduction mode, return light detected";
        case 89:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode, red-eye reduction mode";
        case 93:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode, return light not detected, red-eye reduction mode";
        case 95:
            return @"Flash fired, auto mode, return light detected, red-eye reduction mode";
        default:
            return @"Flash mode unsupported";
    }
}
```

calling the method :

```
NSLog(@"Flash EXIF : %@", [self translateFlashEnumToNSString: [[exifDictionary objectForKey:@"Flash"] integerValue]];
```

Hope it will help.
And for other EXIF key and their description : http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/flash.html